# Editing position in lists

Tags: python, list

When editing a position in a list lets say

```
A=[1,2,3,4]
A[1:-1]
```

returns `2,3` but what if I want it to increase for every lets say `i`
so for a big list or to check if a sentence is a palindrome. After doing it one time I want it to return `a[2:-2]` without making it a loop that loops around a variable. Is there a way to just add values to this without doing it recursively where it automatically loops, or is the only way making it just two variables and changing the variables outside the code?

Comment: There is something called "list comprehension", if you want to read about a possibly shorter syntax. Not sure exactly what you are asking for, though.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, maybe add an example.

Answer (score 1):

Without loops/recursion, I am afraid it isn't possible.
To do this with recursion, lets say this works for you.

```
def recur(arr,i=0,arr1=[]):
  if i==len(arr):
    return arr1
  else:
    arr1.append(arr[i:-i])
    i+=1
    recur(arr,i,arr1)
```

using for loop

```
arr=[1,2,3,4]
arr1=[arr[i:-i] for i in range(len(arr)]
print(arr1)
```

**EDIT**:

This is list comprehension.
true for loop would be

```
arr1=[]
arr=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(arr):
  arr1.append(arr[i:-i])
```

Comment: @Emoanimelovr can you please accept the solution if it had helped you? I need 1 reputation to be able to comment :)